# Rails deeply nested resources alternative to accessing params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, parameters, rails-routing, nested-resources

I have an event model and a Q+A model inside the event.

I'm new to rails so not sure if there is an alternate way to do this

Right now, inside an event `show.html.erb`, I have both a form to post a question, and each question will have a form to post an answer

The routes sit like this right now

```
  resources :events do
    resources :event_questions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

When you create a question inside my `show.html.erb`, it's being routed through `EventQuestionsController` and I access the event_id via params. Do I have to do it the same way with my `event_answer`?

And by that I mean, do I have to nest event_answers inside event_questions. I will need to know the event_id and the event_question_id.

If that's the only way to access the params. Would it look like this?

```
  resources :events do
    resources :event_questions, only: [:create, :destroy] do
       resources :event_answers, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
```

event_questions_controller.rb

```
def create
    @event_question = EventQuestion.new(event_question_params)
    if @event_question.save
        event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @event_question.event = event
        redirect_to event
    else
        redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@event_question, :url => event_event_questions_path(@event)) do |f|  %>
# form stuff
<% end %>
```

I started changing my answer form to this

```
<%= @event.event_questions.each do |q| %>
    <%= q.question %>
    <%= q.fields_for :answers do |a| %>
        <%= a.label :answer %>
        <%= a.text_field :answer %>
        <%= a.submit "Answer" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I posted an answer that may help you, without seeing your controller and the relevant part of your view, it may be hard to assist. However, you shouldn't ever really need to access directly to the id parameters as your code should be able to determine it for you. See my answer below to get an idea of what I'm referring to.

Comment: I added my `event_questions_controller` to give you an idea of what i was doing before. I was going to do something similar with my event_answers_controller. I'm trying to wrap my head around how the form would look for my event_answers. Also, how would I access the variables in my `create`. Can I do the same thing as you have shown?

You can ignore the odd stuff b/c I'm not using a sql DB for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help I derived this answer from a bit of kobaltz answer and some other help.

The alternate method would be putting the information in hidden fields and passing it to the controller

```
   <%= @event.event_questions.each do |q| %>
        <%= q.question %><br>
        <% q.event_answers.each do |a| %>
            <%= a.answer %>
        <% end %>
        <%= form_for(EventAnswer.new) do |f| %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :event_question_id, q.id %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :event_id, @event.id %>
            <%= f.label :answer %>
            <%= f.text_field :answer %>
            <%= f.submit "Answer" %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to directly access the params to create your nested records. For example, if in your `event#new` action, you may have something like

```
@event = Event.new

3.times do
  question = @event.questions.build
  5.times do
    question.answers.build
  end
end
```

This will create a new Event and take you to the New page. Within your New page, you should have nested fields to create and update the nested models.

In the form, you can use `fields_for` to access the associated model's records to that `event` record. In the `new` action case, we are building 3 questions and each question has 5 answers.

```
<%= simple_form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :attribute1 %>
  <%= f.input :attribute2 %>
  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'questions', f: builder %>
  <% end%>
<% end %>
```

I generally like to use a partial when doing nested associations, but if you wanted to keep it all in one file (see below), it would looks something like this.

```
<%= simple_form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :attribute1 %>
  <%= f.input :attribute2 %>
  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |q| %>
    <%= q.input :question_text %>
    <%= q.fields_for :answers do |a| %>
      <%= a.input :answer_text %>
    <% end %>
  <% end%>
<% end %>
```

In your `show` action, you may have something like this

```
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
@questions = @event.questions
@answers = @question.answers if @questions
```

From here, you have three instance variables assigned and able to access the associated records to your events and questions.

Comment: I've added some form examples and controller info. What I don't understand is.. if my routes are not nested, how do I get the event id etc.? when I post to the `create` action